# How to upgrade TableCalendar in table_calendar package?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm using table_calendar in a flutter project. I upgraded it from `^2.3.3` to `^3.0.3`.

This is how the class was used earlier

```
TableCalendar(
      calendarController: _calendarController,
      events: _events,
      initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
      formatAnimation: FormatAnimation.slide,
      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
      availableGestures: AvailableGestures.horizontalSwipe,
      availableCalendarFormats: const {CalendarFormat.month: ''},
      calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(outsideDaysVisible: false),
      headerVisible: true,
      onVisibleDaysChanged: (first, last, format) {
        _statisticsBloc.add(
          StatisticsEvents.getPillsInCalendar(
              first.millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000,
              last.millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000),
        );
      },
      headerStyle: _buildHeaderStyle(context),
      daysOfWeekStyle: _daysOfWeekStyle(),
      rowHeight: 50.h,
      builders: CalendarBuilders(
        dowWeekdayBuilder: _dowWeekdayBuilder,
        dayBuilder: _dayBuilder,
        markersBuilder: (_, date, events, holidays) {
          return isLoading
              ? [
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 2,
                    child: _progressBar(),
                  ),
                ]
              : _markersBuilder(_, date, events, holidays);
        },
      ),
      onDaySelected: (date, events, holidays) =>
          _onDaySelected(date, events, holidays),
    );
```

But in the update, most of these properties are removed therefore almost all the properties are throwing errors(calendarController, events, initialCalendarFormat, formatAnimation, onVisibleDaysChanged, builders, dowWeekdayBuilder, dayBuilder, markersBuilder, onDaySelected) with the upgraded version and I can't seem to figure out what to replace them with. Any help would be great, thanks!